# Clustering algorithms with custom distance function in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I've got a clustering problem that I believe requires an intuitive distance function. Each instance has an x, y coordinate but also has a set of attributes that describe it (varying in number per instance). Ideally it would be possible to pass it pythonobjects (instances of a class) and compare them arbitrarily based on their content.

I want to represent the distance as a weighted sum of the euclidean distance between the x, y values and something like a jaccard index to measure the set overlap of the other attributes. Something like:

```
dist = (euclidean(x1, y1, x2, y2) * 0.6) + (1-jaccard(attrs1, attrs2) * 0.4)
```

Most of the clustering algorithms and implementations I've found convert instance features into numbers. For example with dbscan in sklearn, to do my distance function I would need to convert the numbers back into the original representation somehow.

It would be great if it were possible to do clustering using a distance function that can compare instances in any arbitrary way. For example imagine a euclidean distance function that would evaluate objects as closer if they matched on another non-spatial feature.

```
def dist(ins1, ins2):
     euc = euclidean(ins1.x, ins1.y, ins2.x, ins2.y)
     if ins1.feature1 == ins2.feature1:
          euc = euc * 0.9
     return euc
```

Is there a method that would suit this? It would also be nice if the number of clusters didn't have to be set upfront (but this is not critical for me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, almost all the clustering algorithms (*except* for k-means, which needs numbers to compute the *mean*, obviously) can be used with arbitrary distance functions.

In sklearn, most algorithms accept `metric="precomputed"` and a *distance matrix* instead of the original input data. Please check the documentation more carefully. For example [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html):

> If metric is “precomputed”, X is assumed to be a distance matrix and must be square.

What you lose is the ability to accelerate some algorithms by indexing. Computing a distance matrix is O(n^2), so your algorithm cannot be faster than that. In sklearn, you would need to modify the sklearn Cython code to add a new distance function (using a pyfunc will yield very bad performance, unfortunately). Java tools such as [ELKI can be extended with little overhead](https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/distance_functions) because the Just-in-time compiler of Java optimizes this well. If your distance is *metric* then many indexes can be used for acceleration of e.g. DBSCAN.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about the "precomputed" mode. O(n^2) complexity is fine in my case luckily.